# How do waiting threads affect performance?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I am writing a program which has a relatively expensive calculation when the worst case scenario is reached.  I have tried to dynamically create threads and this has proven to work **most** of the time, but when the worst case scenario comes around, the execution speed is beyond the time I am allotted to complete these calculations, which is largely due to the creation and destruction of these threads.  This has lead me to the idea that I have used in the past, which is creating the threads prior to execution, instead of creating and destroying them dynamically, and having them wait on a condition before performing the calculation instead of creating them dynamically.

Normally I wouldn't think twice about doing this, but because I will be creating lots of threads when the system is initializing, I am concerned with how this will effect the performance of the system.  This has begged a certain question: how do threads that are waiting on a condition effect the system, if at all?  Is creating threads during the program's initializing and only notifying them when I need to perform a calculation the correct way to approach this problem, or does there exist a better solution that I am unaware of?  I have thought about using a threadpool in order to do this, too.  Would a threadpool be best for this situation?

Some information that you may find helpful to better answer this question:

--I am using the boost library (version 1_54_0) in order to multithread the program.

--I am using Windows 7 and Visual Studio.

--If I create the threads when the program initializes, I will be creating 200-1000 threads (this number is predetermined as a #define and I won't necessarily be using all threads every time I need to do the calculation).

--The number of threads needed varies each time I need to perform this calculation; it is dependent on the number of inputs received which changes every time the calculation is performed, but can never exceed a maximum value (the maximum number being determined at compile time as a #define).

--The computer I am using has 32 cores.

I am sorry if this question isn't up to par; I am a new stack overflow user, so feel free to ask for more information and critique me as to how I can better explain the situation and problem.  Thank you in advance for your help!

**UPDATE**

Here is the source code (some variables have been renamed in compliance with my company's terms and conditions)

```
for(int i = curBlob.boundingBoxStartY; i < curBlob.boundingBoxStartY + curBlob.boundingBoxHeight; ++i)
{
    for(int j = curBlob.boundingBoxStartX; j < curBlob.boundingBoxStartX + curBlob.boundingBoxWidth; ++j)
    {
        for(int k = 0; k < NUM_FILTERS; ++k)
        {
            if((int)arrayOfBinaryValues[channel][k].at<uchar>(i,j) == 1)
            {
                for(int p = 0; p < NUM_FILTERS; ++p)
                {
                    if(p != k)
                    {
                        if((curBlob.boundingBoxStartX + 1 < (curBlob.boundingBoxStartX + curBlob.boundingBoxWidth)) && ((int)arrayOfBinaryValues[channel][k].at<uchar>(i + 1,j) == 1))
                            ++count;

                        if((curBlob.boundingBoxStartY + 1 < (curBlob.boundingBoxStartY + curBlob.boundingBoxHeight)) && ((int)arrayOfBinaryValues[channel][k].at<uchar>(i,j + 1) == 1))
                            ++count;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Source code provided is strictly to show the complexity of the algorithm.

Comment: I am suspicious that you even "need" 200-1000 threads. The sheer level of context switching as you reach into 4 digits is going to be dreadful. You may want to consider a pool of threads in a work crew dispatched work via a queue. It eliminates the startup/shutdown time of the queue, and will more than likely parallelize much better, especially if your pool is configured based on a core-count factor.

Comment: @WhozCraig 200 to 1000 threads will have next to no impact on system performance since most of them will be in waiting state. Right now my machine has about 500 active threads and the CPU is basically at 0% (excluding Iceweasel who seems to eat up CPU just when I look at it). However, I couldn't agree more that so many threads are quite likely useless, and a pool of worker threads would be more appropriate.

Comment: @syam I'm not talking about when they're idle; I'm talking about when they're *crunching*. Outside my window is a parking lot full of parked cars that aren't doing anything, but that doesn't mean in a few hours they won't all be sitting in a gridlock of horrid traffic trying to get home (and getting in each *other's* way in the process). I think we both agree that the OP should consider alternatives besides the one-thread-per-activity approach.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, Craig.  Good analogy :)

Comment: Even with CPU-intensive threads, the overhead associated with context-switching flattens out once the number of ready threads exceeds twice the number of cores.  The number of interrupts/second does not magically increase with the number of threads after that point and it's only at interrupts that the OS can context-switch anything.

Comment: Update:  After implementing a pool of worker threads (as suggested by you guys) the program has seen significant improvement to the point where it has not gone beyond the time I am allotted to perform the calculation for the last several hours it has run.  Again, I want to thank you all for your help; your insight has brought me to a new level of understanding regarding how to multithread applications and expensive calculations.  Cheers and best of luck to you all!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the threads are REALLY waiting, they won't consume much resource at all - just a bit of memory, and a few slots of "space" in the waiting list for the scheduler (so there will be a small amount of extra overhead to "wake" or "wait" a thread, as there is a little more data to process - but these queues are usually fairly efficient, so I doubt you'll be able to measure that in an application where the actual threads do some meaningful work).

Of course, if they periodically wake up, even if it's once a second, 1000 threads that wake up once a second means one context switch every millisecond, and that would potentially affect performance.

I do however think that creating MANY threads is the wrong solution in nearly all cases. Unless the logic in the threads is complex, and there is a huge amount of state/context to track for each thread, and this state or context is not easy to store somewhere, it may be correct to do this. But in most cases, I'd say using a small number of worker threads, and then having a queue of work items (including [some type of reference to] their respective state or context) will be a better method to achieve this.

**Edit** based on edit in question:

Since (as far as I can tell) the thread is completely bound by CPU (or memory bandwidth) - there is no I/O or other "waiting around", the maximum performance will be achieved by running one thread per core in the system (possibly "minus one" for "other stuff that needs doing, such as communicating via network, disk I/O, and general OS/system work that needs to be done).

Having more threads than the number of cores may even cause the processing to be SLOWER, if there are more threads ready to run than there are cores on the CPU, because now the OS will have multiple threads "fighting" for time, and this will cause extra thread scheduling effort on the part of the OS, and on top of that when one thread runs, it will load up the cache with useful content. When another thread gets to run on that same CPU core, it will force the cache to load other data into the cache, and when the "old" thread gets to run again, even if it's on the same CPU, it will have to reload the data it was using.

I will do a quick experiment and come back with some numbers for one of my projects...

So, I have a small project that calculates "[weird numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weird_number)". I use it here as a "comparison as of the time it takes to run one vs. more threads". Each thread here uses fairly little memory - a few hundred bytes, so cache will probably have no effect at all. So the only variable here is the "startup cost" and marginal overhead due to competition between threads. The number of threads is dictated by the `-t` option. The `-e` is "what number to stop at".

```
$ time ./weird -t 1 -e 50000 > /dev/null

real    0m6.393s
user    0m6.359s
sys 0m0.003s
$ time ./weird -t 2 -e 50000 > /dev/null

real    0m3.210s
user    0m6.376s
sys 0m0.013s
$ time ./weird -t 4 -e 50000 > /dev/null

real    0m1.643s
user    0m6.397s
sys 0m0.024s
$ time ./weird -t 8 -e 50000 > /dev/null

real    0m1.641s
user    0m6.397s
sys 0m0.028s
$ time ./weird -t 16 -e 50000 > /dev/null

real    0m1.644s
user    0m6.385s
sys 0m0.047s
$ time ./weird -t 256 -e 50000 > /dev/null

real    0m1.790s
user    0m6.420s
sys 0m0.342s
$ time ./weird -t 512 -e 50000 > /dev/null

real    0m1.779s
user    0m6.439s
sys 0m0.502s
```

As you can see, the amount of time to "run" the whole project improves from 1 to 2 and from 2 to 4 threads. But running more than 4 threads give almost identical results until we get to the hundreds (I skipped over a few steps in doubling the number of threads).

Now, to show the scheduling overhead, I upped the number of "numbers to find" with a bigger number after `-e` (this also makes the process run for longer, as the bigger numbers are more complex to calculate).

```
$ time ./weird -t 512 -e 100000 > /dev/null

real    0m7.100s
user    0m26.195s
sys 0m1.542s
$ time ./weird -t 4 -e 100000 > /dev/null

real    0m6.663s
user    0m26.143s
sys 0m0.049s
```

Now, if it was ONLY the startup time that cost, we should see similar overhead (in `sys`) between the 512 threads going to 50000 and the 512 threads going to 100000, but we are seeing a three times higher number. So, out of 6-7 seconds, running 512 threads (at full speed) vs running 4 threads wastes nearly 1.5s of CPU time (or about 0.4s per CPU). Sure, it's only about 5%, but 5% of wasted effort is still wasted. There are a lot of cases where a 5% improvement in algorithm is "worth having".

Yes, this is an extreme case, and it could be argued that as long as most threads are waiting, it doesn't really matter.

Comment: Is the approach of creating a small number of worker threads and then having a queue of work items essentially a thread pool?

Comment: Yes, that's another name for the same thing (or at least, it amounts to the same thing in general - I'm sure "Thread Pool" is pretty specific).

Comment: I will attempt this approach and let you know how it goes.  Might be a while as I am still very new to multi-threading, and have never implemented a thread pool before.  Thanks for your help though, it is much appreciated! :)

Comment: I must admit, I've only done a very simple approach for this particular scenario - and I have used threads in the dozens on a single core 286 or 386, where each thread was controlling it's own piece of hardware. It worked fine that way. But more than a couple of dozen threads seem to be the wrong solution to most problems - unless you have some very weird hardware, where there is hundreds or thousands of hardware instances to look after.

Comment: In my experience with multithreading, I have never made more than a couple threads that work in parallel (at most I'd say somewhere between 5 and 10).  The computation I am trying to perform is very intense though. It's about 15 ms for each item I receive when input is received.  I feel like where I get lost is that I don't understand why creating the 200 threads and notifying only the threads I need when the calculation needs to be performed is not the correct solution, or rather the optimal solution, especially when on average I will only be notifying 20 threads each time I receive an input.

Comment: Well, you can solve it that way if you like, but it's a waste of memory if nothing else, as each thread has it's own stack (quite often 1-8MB per thread), and if there are more threads than the number of CPU(cores), you won't "gain" anything anyway, over a method where you have a lower number of threads and each thread picks some work when their previous work is finished.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense.  One last question, if you don't mind: In terms of speed, though, which do you think would be faster?  I have about 64 gigs of memory (ram, of course) so I'm not overly concerned with memory problems and I need this calculation to go as fast as I can make it go.

Comment: I have updated my answer with the code of the calculation I am performing so you can see the complexity.

Comment: @ChrisEddington I concur with Mats update and add this: If this is a giant work-batch you're splitting into threads (one blob per thread) you may consider portioning that work-batch of size M into M/N "chunks", where N is the core count and M/N becomes the number of blobs each thread crunches (with the last thread getting the additional M % N blobs. I hope I said that clear enough. This would minimize your thread count while keeping each of them as busy as possible (since each has independent work and requires *no* synchronization with the other threads).

Comment: Okay now I am understanding what you are saying.  I really can't express how helpful you have been and I wish I could give you an up vote but I don't have enough karma :( lol.  Honestly, though, this has been incredibly insightful and I appreciate you taking the time to help.  Thanks!